# Typical Objective C message implementation

Tags: objective-c

I'm wondering how does a typical (or at least Apple's) implementation of the Objective C dynamic messaging system look. How are selectors handled at compile and run time, what does `NSObject*` really point at, how is the method implementation found in there.

In C++, we have virtual functions; how they are implemented is officially an implementation detail, but in reality a VF table pointer as a first data member is pretty much a given. I'm wondering if there's a similarly ubiquitous way of implementing ObjC's class system.

Comment: bbum’s [objc_msgSend() Tour](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/12/18/objc_msgsend-part-1-the-road-map/) is a great read.

Comment: @Bavarious: make this an answer, please. Once I read to the end, I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be quite lengthy. ughoavgfhw’s answer is a good start.

I’d recommend reading the following blog posts:

- bbum’s objc_msgSend() Tour Parts [1](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/12/18/objc_msgsend-part-1-the-road-map/), [2](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/12/18/objc_msgsend-tour-part-2-setting-the-stage/), [3](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/12/18/objc_msgsend-tour-part-3-the-fast-path/), [4](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/02/04/objc_msgsend-tour-part-4-method-lookup-some-odds-and-ends/)
- mikeash’s [Friday Q&A 2009-03-20: Objective-C Messaging](http://mikeash.com/pyblog//friday-qa-2009-03-20-objective-c-messaging.html)

And if you’re not afraid of delving into source code, [objc](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437.1/) and [clang](http://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-23/) are available at [Apple’s Open Source Web site](http://opensource.apple.com).

Answer (score 3):

Check out the headers in `/usr/include/objc` on your nearest development Mac for some of the low-level object details. (Apple has changed some things in the new runtime, but many of the changes haven't been published. Details on the original implementation can be found in these headers, or by googling "objective c runtime".) Some highlights: An object is simply a structure containing the instance variables. The first element in this structure is called `isa`, and is simply a pointer to the class object (or superclass for a class object). The class object contains data specifying the name and location of different methods and variables within the class, and the runtime references these data structures when looking up a method. Once a method has been looked up the first time, it is stored in a table for quick future reference.

Comment: My understanding was that there was an extra level of indirection for instance variables as of 10.5, to completely eliminate the fragile base class problem and hence why they can now be added dynamically to an extent?

Comment: @Tommy You’re right. When using the modern runtime (x86_64, iOS), the compiler emits code that uses a variable (runtime) ivar offset when accessing an ivar, whereas access to traditional structure members is done via an offset computed and fixed at compile time.

Comment: @Tommy Yes, that is why I said that you will mostly find details about the original runtime. However, the class pointer at the start of the structure is still the same (it's part of the definition of `id`), and I believe the class objects use similar structures, though apple doesn't declare it as such, instead providing abstraction barrier functions.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's official [Objective-C Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) documents the C library that provides all of Objective-C's dispatches, reflection and other object-oriented tasks. Most of the actual data structures used are opaque — I think all of them are since 10.5 — and there's no reason to suppose a continuous line in implementation back to 1986.

The compiler just converts your Objective-C stuff into calls to the runtime; you can also call it yourself to get things like C function pointers to your methods, which you can then dispatch to without the normal overhead though at the cost of a whole bunch of other mechanisms no longer working.